# why can't I run this query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to run this query

```
$tableDate = DB::select('SELECT (DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%m-%d-%Y")) as 
   dateTaken FROM `test_answers`WHERE user_id= '.$id.' GROUP BY (test_id) 
');
```

but it is giving me this error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'mte30.test_answers.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT (DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%m-%d-%Y")) as dateTaken FROM test_answers WHERE user_id= 2 GROUP BY (test_id) )

I tried it on PHPMyAdmin and it worked.
Can someone tell me why it's not working using Eloquent?

Thank you

Comment: Check your config in `config/database.php`; if you see `'strict' => true,` in your active connection, you can change that to `'strict' => false,` to get rid of that error. Not sure if there's any downsides/drawbacks to that though.

Comment: I read it's bad to do that; however, I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Did you remember to clear your config cache?

Comment: Are all of the created_at dates the same for each test_id?

Comment: clearing the cache helped thank you. Is it safe to keep 'strict' => false? Would there be sql injection?

Comment: It has nothing to do with SQL injections, it has to do with MySQL's strict mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work with strict mode on is because you haven't specified in the query which created_at to use.   If you're using GROUP BY and you are selecting a column that isn't grouped on or aggregated, you may not receive the correct data.

You have multiple rows in test_answers but MySQL doesn't know which row's created_at you care about.  You could fix this by simply telling MySQL which created_at to return, something like `MAX(created_at)` to select the most recent, or `MIN(created_at)` to select the oldest.

Comment: Glad I could help, you can select this as the accepted answer to close out the question.